# JQuery UI Buttonset in UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, updatepanel

I have a server control which has a couple of radio buttons on it. I run a startup javascript script file which applied the JQuery UI buttonset() on them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#radiobuttonpanelid%').buttonset();
});
```

Everything works perfectly when outside of an UpdatePanel. If the server control is inside an update panel, no matter what I try, i get "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'buttonset'". I get this message even the first time I open the page.

Update:
Rendered HTML when inside of the update panel looks like this:

```
<DIV>
    <SPAN>
        <INPUT name=ct1 id=ct1 type=radio CHECKED value=1>
        <LABEL for=ct1>1</LABEL>
    </SPAN> 
    <BR>
</DIV>
<DIV>
    <SPAN>
        <INPUT name=ct2 id=ct2 type=radio value=2>
        <LABEL for=ct2>2</LABEL>
    </SPAN>
    <BR>
</DIV>
```

Anyone came across this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the *rendered* html when it's inside the update panel?

Comment: I updated the original post